# Why pass string that represents an object instead passing the object?

Tags: python, django, object

Code below is from `Django`'s `settings.py`. Since everything in `Python` is an object, why don't just pass installed apps as tuple of objects:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  django.contrib.auth,
  django.contrib.contenttypes,
.....
```

Is there some strong reason why they do this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
.....
```

instead?

I'm new to `Python` and `Django`, so don't judge me too much, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing module or class name as a string is typical solution to avoiding circular import error.
For example, if settings file contains `import myapp.models` and myapp.models contains `from django.conf import settings` this would lead to circular import.

Comment: Great. This explains everything

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to `import django` and so first to make it work, otherwise you'll have an error.

Comment: So it is `Django`'s settings. Why don't import `django`? This modules/libs/classes/whatever will be loaded anyway, right?

Comment: Because it's easier to read and shorter - if you have long list of installed apps, you'd have to import many modules. I didn't try it, but it should work if Django is internally capable of dealing with objects in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: For example MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES has something like this: 

`( 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware', 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' )`

- How do you imagine that many imports?

Comment: How is it easier to read? `'django.contrib.something'` vs `django.contrib.something`? Second is easier to me.

Comment: Then importing module and including it isn't [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: `How do you imagine that many imports?`. All of this needs only `import django` :) So, I can imagine :) Really.... Maybe I'm missing something or just not getting your point.....

Comment: You'd also have to start importing other modules for your own custom applications. Its not a style/readability issue, its to do with the order of imports as Alex Lebedev's answer explains.

Comment: @Nemoden `import blog; import news; import comments;` and many, many other INSTALLED_APPS in big project...

Comment: Oh... Since I've turned to the wrong road from very beginning of using `Django` I still have only 1 application `blog` where I do all the stuff that should be separated to distinguished apps... So it  wouldn't be hard for me to just `import django` and `blog`. Ok. This is the reason too. Thanks for clarification and spending your time!